# How to open link from packaged`s app web-view into default browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

There is a messenger chrome packaged app with webView inside. How I can open links from messenger in browser?

Project is open source: https://github.com/clicman/OdSkype

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Intercepting the navigation request, or opening the result in the browser?

Comment: Problem in opening link in browser. App is in separate process and I have no idea how to tell to it  to open links in browser. As I see it trying to open it in application context, not in browser.

Comment: That sounds like both problems at once. The problem can be split into 2 parts: 1) Intercept the webview trying to navigate to `url`, prevent it and pass it to a function that 2) will open `url` in the default browser or Chrome specifically. Have you solved part 1?

Comment: for 1) I`ve added listener to webView with "newwindow" event, prevent default propagation and called window.open. problem exactly in 2nd case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `url` is the URL you want to open in a browser from a Chrome App, you have 2 possibilities:

1. Opening the URL in the user's default browser:

   ```
   window.open(url);
   ```
2. Opening the URL in Chrome specifically, regardless of the default browser setting, there's [a recent API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser):

   ```
   chrome.browser.openTab({url: url});
   ```

   This requires `"browser"` permission.

Comment: Excellent! It just needed to add "browser" permission to manifest. Thank you!

Comment: Note that if you call `window.open` from the app's background (event) page, and your default browser is Chrome, the resulting tab will have no access to `window.localStorage`, which means, for example, that any page that requires some sort of authentication or depends on cookies will be broken. It's a known bug, but it's significance has now been diminished by `chrome.browser.openTab`. Still, `window.open` should have been somehow marked deprecated for Chrome apps (print a diagnostic maybe).

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko Please define "known bug" in terms of an issue number.

Comment: Except window.open is the only way to open an app page in a tab.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm an issue. Open fb.com from app event via window.open crashes an opened tab.

Comment: The stress was on the "background (event) page". From a foreground page, everything works fine. The Chrome issues are [252464](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=252464) and [358315](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=358315) (the former was merged into latter). And no, like Xan and I have mentioned, `window.open` is no longer the only way to open a URL in a tab: `chrome.browser.openTab` has shipped in Chrome 42 stable channel.

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko Thanks for the two links. The merge is not fully justified.

Comment: @Xan: I know, and I commented along those lines in the former bug :)